# Laravel loop on model and change to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to change my model to xml format.

I did almost everything but I still need this thing:

```
$data = [
            'domain'=> $xmlDocument->domain,
            'FirstDate' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->first_date,
            'LastDate' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->last_date,
            'Category' => $xmlDocument->category->name,
            'Action' => $xmlDocument->websiteAction->name,
            'Source' => $xmlDocument->source->name,
            'LogFile' => $xmlDocument->log_file,
            'DateAttribute' => [
                        'Name' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->name,
                        'Place' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->dateLocation->name,
                        'DateFunction' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->dateFunction->name
                    ],
            'MasterPage' => [
                'MasterAttributes' => [

                ],
                'Container'=>[
                    'xpath' => $xmlDocument->masterInformation->xpath
                ],
                'NextPage' =>[],
                'LinkAttribute'=>[]
            ],
        ];
```

as you see the `MasterAttributes` is empty.

the model `$xmlDocument` has a one to many relationship like this:

```
$xmlDocument->masterInformaton->masterAttributes
```

the `masterAttributes` is the many part

#### My question

how to use that many and transfer it to array, so each element in that array is this:

```
'masterAttribute' => [
    'name' => ...,
    'xpath' => ...
]
```

In other words, I will have many arrays and these arrays will be added to the **empty** MasterAttribute key in the code I showed to u.

I hope I made my point to you, if not, kindly tell me.

#### Update

What I have tried:

```
$masterAttributes = [];
        foreach ($xmlDocument->masterInformation->masterAttributes as $attribute){
            $masterAttribute = [
                'Attribute' =>[
                    'defaultValue' => $attribute->defaultValue,
                    'name' => $attribute->attributeName->name,
                    'xpath' => $attribute->xpath
                ]
            ];
            array_push($masterAttributes, $masterAttribute);
        }
```

and then I put the result like this:

```
'MasterAttributes' => [
                    $masterAttributes
                ],
```

but the generated xml is:

```
<MasterAttributes>
         <item0>
            <item0>
               <Attribute>
                  <defaultValue />
                  <name>bathroom</name>
                  <xpath>this is the xpath</xpath>
               </Attribute>
            </item0>
            <item1>
               <Attribute>
                  <defaultValue />
                  <name>price</name>
                  <xpath>new xpath</xpath>
               </Attribute>
            </item1>
            <item2>
               <Attribute>
                  <defaultValue />
                  <name>bathroom</name>
                  <xpath>new xpath value</xpath>
               </Attribute>
            </item2>
         </item0>
      </MasterAttributes>
```

look that there is extra `Item2` and `item0` that I don't want

#### Update 2

The code to generate the xml is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><websiteInformation></websiteInformation>");
        $this->array_to_xml($data,$xml);
        $xml->asXML("FileName".XmlDocument::find($id)->id.".xml");
```

where `$data` is the final array I showed to you and `array_to_xml` is:

```
// function defination to convert array to xml
    public  function array_to_xml($student_info, &$xml_student_info) {
        foreach($student_info as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!is_numeric($key)){
                    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("$key");
                    $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }
                else{
                    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item$key");
                    $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }
            }
            else {
                $xml_student_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Updadte 3

The `@watcher` gave me an aswer and this is the result of his/her answer

```
<MasterAttributes>
         <item0>
            <masterAttribute>
               <name />
               <xpath>this is the xpath</xpath>
            </masterAttribute>
         </item0>
         <item1>
            <masterAttribute>
               <name />
               <xpath>new xpath</xpath>
            </masterAttribute>
         </item1>
         <item2>
            <masterAttribute>
               <name />
               <xpath>new xpath value</xpath>
            </masterAttribute>
         </item2>
      </MasterAttributes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$attributes = $xmlDocument->masterInformaton->masterAttributes;
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    $data['MasterPage']['MasterAttributes'][] = [
        'masterAttribute' => [
            'name' => $attribute->name,
            'xpath' => $attribute->xpath,
        ]
    ];
}
```

This is assuming that the attributes on your master attributes are `name` and `xpath`.

**Update**

```
$subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item$key");
```

This is the line in your xml generation that is adding those `item0` nodes.  Removing that doesn't help, because you do need to build a subtree based off of these indices, but you don't want to add them directly to the XML document as they are.

I tried coming up with a quick solution, but it turns out its not so quick (I also found I think the original answer where you found your xml generation code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940/697370)).

**Update 2**

Try using this for your xml generation, see if it gets you what you need.  It's based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24763517/697370) by @drzaus:

```
function simple_xmlify($arr, SimpleXMLElement $root = null, $el = 'x') {
    // based on, among others https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397164/1037948

    if(!isset($root) || null == $root) $root = new SimpleXMLElement('<' . $el . '/>');

    if(is_array($arr)) {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
            // special: attributes
            if(is_string($k) && $k[0] == '@') $root->addAttribute(substr($k, 1),$v);
            // normal: append
            else {
                if(is_numeric($k) && is_array($v)) {
                    foreach($v as $ik => $iv) {
                        simple_xmlify($iv, $root);
                    }
                } else {
                    simple_xmlify($v, $root->addChild(
                        // fix 'invalid xml name' by prefixing numeric keys
                        is_numeric($k) ? 'n' . $k : $k)
                    );
                }

            }
        }
    } else {
        $root[0] = $arr;
    }

    return $root;
}//--   fn  simple_xmlify
```

Comment: I just updated the question before I saw you answer and it seems that I was doing close to your answer, let me test it and I will update you +1 anyway

Comment: I updated the answer a bit, trying to get it to match what you stated you want the output to be in better.

Comment: I dont' know but the answer has not been updated yet. are you sure you have?

Comment: Yes, it was a slight change.  I assume you're using foreach to iterate through the array to generate the xml, and I think the reason you're getting those extra keys is due to numeric indices that you're wanting to not include as xml elements.  Can you update the question with the code you're using to generate the xml?

Comment: but how to put your result in my final array?

Comment: the code to generate the xml is 100 % correct, because as you see, I already include one to one relationship when I used `'DateAttribute' ` any way I will give you the code

Comment: please where do you save the results so I can put it in the final array?

Comment: got u you are saving it directly to the `$data`

Comment: I updated the question and put the answer of your code

Comment: yeah, Im just putting it directly in your data, sorry I missed that comment.  looking into your xml generation now

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent see Update 2, that seems to be working for me locally.

Comment: I got too confused and I dont want to change something I worked hard to do. I will accept yoru answer and start a new thread, thanks a lot for the efforts

Comment: np, glad to help, sorry it took so long

Comment: don't be sorry please. I am thankful and gradful to your efforts with me.